# Scroll event not registered in body element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

There is a strange issue in **firefox**, scrolling in the iframe body does not bubble to the parent document. So when you are finished scrolling inside the iframe,it gets stuck and doesnt scroll the parent document.
**Any workaround for this issue is welcome.**
My approach for this is getting scroll event on scrolling the iframe document, so that i can manually scroll the parent document.But i am not getting the scroll event when the iframe document is fully scrolled to the top or bottom.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tdu9197g/

Due to cross origin policy it is not working in the stackoverflow snippet. Please try the fiddle in firefox.

```js
$(function(){
  $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).find('body').css('height',200);
  $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).find('body').on('click',function(){
     $('iframe')[0].contentDocument.designMode='on';
  })
  $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).find('body').on('blur',function(){
    console.log('blur called');
  });
  $('body').on('click',function(){
     $('iframe')[0].contentDocument.designMode='off';
  });
  $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).find('body').on('scroll',function(){
     console.log('scroll');
  })
  $($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).find('body').on('mouseover',function(){
   console.log('scroll');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div>
<iframe>
  
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: In your fiddle the scrolling element is the iframe, so this: `$($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).on('scroll',function(){
     console.log('scroll');
  })` should print `scroll` on scroll

Comment: yeah, i edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't attach to the `body` element of the `iframe` `contentDocument`.

Attach the event handler to the `contentDocument` itself:

```
$($('iframe')[0].contentDocument).on('scroll',function(){
    console.log('scroll');
})
```

This registers the scroll event handler and the console displays the result of the `console.log` statement.

Comment: I just noticed that my approach will not work, because when the iframebody is fully scrolled and user continues to scroll, then there is no scroll event registered. Any suggestions. @beerwin

Comment: When you are scrolling and hit the top/bottom of the document, and continue to scroll to the same direction, the scroll command is sent, but no scroll event is being triggered. Events are triggered only, when a related command was successfully executed. When you hit the bottom and keep scrolling down, there will be no successful execution. This is why you have no event triggered. In this case, you should fiddle with mouse events, instead of the scroll event.